# Automatically exclude ignored directory in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, gitignore, jetbrains-ide

I have a monorepo with a lot of build directories. These are ignored in the `.gitignore` file but if I analyze the project or open one of the files inside WebStorm still analyzes them and reports tons of errors.

I can prevent this by manually excluding each folder but there's tons of them.

Is there a way to tell WebStorm that any ignored file should also be excluded from analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, if you open `.gitignore`, there will be a message right at the top offering to exclude everything that is ignored but not excluded yet.
It should make it easier to exclude everything that is ignored.

Comment: How to do the reverse of the above? I chose to exclude everything in `.gitignore` and now I want to revert that change.

Comment: @Jagan they are added to the excluded directories list in settings